# Hidden fields in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm not sure if I understand the "hidden" attribute when making comments to a post. I wrote the code below, to "aim" the comment towards the post_id

```
   <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{$post->id}}" >
```

Other people seem to use this "hidden" method to find the post_id as well. The problem is, when I inspect the elements and write "3" in the value, it allows me to write a comment on an entirely different blog post.

Is there some way to validate the post_id or make it impossible to use "inspect elements".

This is what the commentStore controller looks like

```
public function storeComment(request $request)
{

$post = $request->post_id;
$id = Auth::id();

Comment::create([
    'body' => $request->body,
    'user_id' => $id,
    'post_id' => $post
]);

return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If users should only be able to post comments on certain posts, [use an authorization policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization) to authorize the request, and only permit their comments where they should be permitted.

If users should be able to post *anywhere*, don't worry about it. The user's not really doing anything they're not supposed to in that scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I understand your way of thinking. The user has no benefit in posting his reply on some other post, so there's no reason to validate it, because the user is free to post a comment on any blog post.

Answer (score 1):

i have read the answer by `@ceejayoz` and it looks good

But if You Application is small scale and you dont need to implement the `authorization` policies there is as way

Problems in your `hidden attribute`

it Wiil be readable by the user by using `view::source` or even can `inspect` the page and `rewrite` it

**Solution**

What we are doing

Encrypting the `post_id` in the hidden attribute of the form and `decrypting it the controller`

For the encryption Docs refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/encryption

**Follow the steps**

> Views

**From**

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{$post->id}}" >
```

To

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{Crypt::encrypt($post->id)}}" >
```

Now the `post_id` is encryptd in the form

> Controller

Add this namespace to top of controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;
```

Add this function to your controller

```
public function decryptId($encryptedId='',$message='Not Found',$statusCode=404)
    {
        try {

            $decrypted =Crypt::decrypt($encryptedId);

            return $decrypted;

            } catch (DecryptException $e) 
            {
            abort($statusCode,$message);
            }
    }
```

and Your `storeComment`

```
public function storeComment(request $request)
{

$postIdEncrypted = $request->post_id;

$postIdDecrypted = self::decryptId($postIdEncrypted);

$post = $postIdDecrypted;
$id = Auth::id();

Comment::create([
    'body' => $request->body,
    'user_id' => $id,
    'post_id' => $post
]);

return redirect('/');
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This still allows for repetition attacks where an attacker remembers the encrypted identifier of one post and uses it on another form (or worse, shares it with the world).

Comment: yes **Accepted** but have you read the line **But if You Application is small scale** in my answer

Comment: and for your notice each time encryting the same value will results in different  value

Comment: What has scale to do with security? Absolutely nothing. Every developer has an obligation to keep security in mind, especially when writing software that is used in the open web. And besides that, you are right that the value is different due to different MACs and initialization vectors, but it doesn't matter when it comes to reusability of encrypted codes. Repetition attacks will still work.

Comment: Thank you taking your time to explain security. I'm not sure if this method of encrypting and decrypting is useful for this current project. But I do see a lot of value in future projects. I will save your explanation into my notes and keep it safe for a moment where I feel like a projects needs this kind of validation. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: yes . I will use while CRED Opration of the model and its good